# How to downgrade/configure elder Mono in Visual Studio For Mac?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, mono, visual-studio-mac

I am trying to build old code with `Visual Studio For Mac` and getting the following error:

```
Target XamlC:
    Compiling Xaml
    
    Assembly: obj/Debug/OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms.dll
...
    /Users/.../MyProject/packages/Xamarin.Forms.2.3.3.193/build/portable-win+net45+wp80+win81+wpa81+MonoAndroid10+Xamarin.iOS10+xamarinmac20/Xamarin.Forms.targets(62,3): error MSB4018: The "XamlCTask" task failed unexpectedly.
    /Users/.../MyProject/packages/Xamarin.Forms.2.3.3.193/build/portable-win+net45+wp80+win81+wpa81+MonoAndroid10+Xamarin.iOS10+xamarinmac20/Xamarin.Forms.targets(62,3): error MSB4018: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file "/Users/.../MyProject/OxyPlot/OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms/obj/Debug/OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms.dll.mdb"
    /Users/.../MyProject/packages/Xamarin.Forms.2.3.3.193/build/portable-win+net45+wp80+win81+wpa81+MonoAndroid10+Xamarin.iOS10+xamarinmac20/Xamarin.Forms.targets(62,3): error MSB4018: File name: '/Users/.../MyProject/OxyPlot/OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms/obj/Debug/OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms.dll.mdb'
    /Users/.../MyProject/packages/Xamarin.Forms.2.3.3.193/build/portable-win+net45+wp80+win81+wpa81+MonoAndroid10+Xamarin.iOS10+xamarinmac20/Xamarin.Forms.targets(62,3): error MSB4018: 
    /Users/.../MyProject/packages/Xamarin.Forms.2.3.3.193/build/portable-win+net45+wp80+win81+wpa81+MonoAndroid10+Xamarin.iOS10+xamarinmac20/Xamarin.Forms.targets(62,3): error MSB4018: 
    /Users/.../MyProject/packages/Xamarin.Forms.2.3.3.193/build/portable-win+net45+wp80+win81+wpa81+MonoAndroid10+Xamarin.iOS10+xamarinmac20/Xamarin.Forms.targets(62,3): error MSB4018: Server stack trace: 
...
```

I [read here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/error-msb4018-the-xamlctask-task-failed-unexpected/242678), that it is possible to use elder Mono (4.8) to build project. How to do this?

Comment: that reference is 4 years old

Comment: Depending on an out-of-maintenance package (not updated for years) is the problem, and downgrading Mono is just overkill as it also breaks VS for Mac. If you don't find a fork that resolves the issue for you, time to get rid of that `OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms` dependency or make a fork of your own https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot-xamarin/network

Comment: So? Is it possible anymore?

Comment: @LexLi in Java world I can choose runtime of building independently of runtime of IDE. isn't it possible for Mono? I agree to downgrade entire VS anyway....

Comment: Parallel Mono installation is possible, but nobody really wanted to do that, https://www.mono-project.com/docs/compiling-mono/parallel-mono-environments/

Comment: This is possible, but not really supported. The last official Mono 4.8 installer - https://dl.xamarin.com/MonoFrameworkMDK/Macx86/MonoFramework-MDK-4.8.0.524.macos10.xamarin.universal.pkg - VS Mac has a way to configure the active mono runtime but it is hidden behind a RUNTIME_SELECTOR feature flag which then enables .NET Runtimes in preferences under the Projects section. The easiest way to enable the feature flag is to install the feature switch addin from the Extensions manager - then go into preferences - Environment - Feature switch, enable RUNTIME_SELECTOR and restart VS Mac.